# Add last review date for a heading

Tags: org-mode

I want to add a last-reviewed date for some headings.

And in org agenda view, I want to filter outer the headings that have not been reviewed for some days.

What's the org tools/functions/setup that are involved here?

Comment: Probably a [property](https://orgmode.org/manual/Properties-and-Columns.html#Properties-and-Columns) and a [custom agenda view](https://orgmode.org/manual/Custom-Agenda-Views.html#Custom-Agenda-Views).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can store the review date as an org-mode timestamp in a property, say `LAST_REVIEW`.  To help input them, you can use `org-property-set-functions-alist` to give function that will be called when setting the property with `C-c C-x p`:

```
(add-to-list 'org-property-set-functions-alist
             '("LAST_REVIEW" . (lambda (&rest args)
                                  (format "[%s]"
                                          (org-read-date nil nil nil
                                                         "Last Reviewed on")
                                          ))))
```

(Here I'm using an inactive timestampe. Change "[%s]" to "<%s>" if you prefer active.)

You can query properties in the agenda view. For example the query `LAST_REVIEW<"<-1m>"` Will find entries whose `LAST_REVIEW` property is older than 1 month.  You can save it in a custom agenda view:

```
(add-to-list 'org-agenda-custom-commands
             '("r" "Items to review"
               tags "LAST_REVIEW<\"<-1m>\""
               ))
```

Comment: An inactive timestamp is the right choice: active ones would wreak havoc on the agenda.

Comment: Active timestamps in properties don't always appear in the agenda. Its changed back and forth from version to version